# Did the formation of the first atoms increase or decrease the entropy at that very moment?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

If the formation increased it, then how
 trapping a large amounts of energy in a single atom increased entropy? 
Is it possible that entropy was decreased?
What  other examples of decreasing entropy exist?.

Comment: The universe is not solely made up of atoms. It also has photons as well. In addition, the act of combining an electron and a nucleus into an atom releases energy in the form of photons. What happens to the photon entropy after you add all of that recombination light?